# ASP.NET MVC - If an error happens and the view is returned, uploaded file is not returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, file-upload

I created a form that gives the user an option to upload a PDF file using an input with a file type.  If an error occurs and the view is returned, the file is no longer there.  I've been researching for hours, and everyone is saying that it would be a security risk or whatever if that functionality was available, but surely there is something that can be done so the user doesn't have to resubmit the file?  The user may not notice that their file is no longer there and it just doesn't seem like good UX to make the user do that.  Any thoughts?  I'd appreciate any feedback on either a fix or a different way to handle this scenario.

Comment: As people mentioned before. Auto resubmit is not allowed. The best way I can think of handling this situation is using Asynchronous calls (AJAX), then, the user will asynchronously submit the file, and you will store it in a temp folder, proccess it, if there is any error you would be able to show them to the user, and if not you can read the file from the temp folder. You could always schedule a cleanup job to remove old temp files.

Comment: Okay I get what you are saying.  Do you know of any examples for reading the file from the temp folder and showing it on the view?

Comment: Lets say you have `HttpPostedFileBase` called `file` as a variable in your code.
You can just use ```PHP
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
  {
     var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
     var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/"), fileName);
     file.SaveAs(path);
  }
```
To store the file, then just remember the name, you can also use `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` to generate a "random" name, and just "remember it".

Then, to read you can just `File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/"), fileName));` to return all bytes.